# Factor sets and group extensions (Homological algebra- Hilton and Stammbach VI.10.1)

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, group-extensions

Show that an extension $$A\xrightarrow{i} E\xrightarrow{p} G$$ may be described by a factor set, as follows. Let $s:G\rightarrow E$ be a secion so that $ps=1_G$. Every elmenet of $E$ is of the form $i(a).s(x)$  with $a,x$ uniquely determined. The multiplication in $E$ determined a function $f:G\times G\rightarrow A$ by $$s(x)\cdot s(x')=i(f(x,x'))\cdot s(xx')$$
for all $x,x'\in G$.

---

i) Show that associativity of multiplication in $E$ implies 
$$xf(y,z)-f(xy,z)+f(x,yz)-f(x,y)=0$$
A function satisfying above condition is called a factor set.

---

ii) Show that if $s,s': G\rightarrow E$ be two sections and $f,f'$ be corresponding factor sets then there exists a function $g:G\rightarrow A$ with $$f'(x,y)=f(x,y)+g(xy)-g(x)-xg(y)$$ for all $x,y\in G$

---

I tried something like this :

As any element in $E$ is of the form $i(a)s(g)$

Consider $$i(a)s(g)i(b)s(h)=i(a)i(gb)s(g)s(h)$$
$$=i(a+gb)i(f(g,h))s(gh)$$
$$=i(a+gb+f(g,h))s(gh)$$

So, group law on $A\times G$ is given by $$(a,g)(b,h)=(a+gb+f(g,h),gh)$$

So, $$((a,g)(b,h))(c,m)=(a+gb+f(g,h)+ghc+f(gh,m),ghm)$$

and $$(a,g)((b,h),(c,m))=(a+gb+ghc+gf(h,m)+f(g,hm),ghm)$$

As suggested i use associativity of elements in $E$ and conlcuded that

$$(a+gb+f(g,h)+ghc+f(gh,m),ghm)=(a+gb+ghc+gf(h,m)+f(g,hm),ghm)$$

i.e., $$f(g,h)+f(gh,m)=gf(h,m)+f(g,hm)$$

So, we have $$xf(y,z)-f(xy,z)+f(x,yz)-f(x,y)=0$$ for all $x,x'\in G$

---

I am not sure how to proceed with second part...

I do not even understand what he is trying to ask.. Suppose we have sections $s,s'$ we have corresponding $f,f'$ and for this we have

$$xf(y,z)-f(xy,z)+f(x,yz)-f(x,y)=0=xf'(y,z)-f'(xy,z)+f'(x,yz)-f'(x,y)$$

i.e., $$-xf(y,z)+f(xy,z)-f(x,yz)+f(x,y)=-xf'(y,z)+f'(xy,z)-f'(x,yz)+f'(x,y)$$ 
i.e., $$f'(x,y)=f(x,y)-xf(y,z)+f(xy,z)-f(x,yz)+xf'(y,z)-f'(xy,z)+f'(x,yz)$$

I define $g:G\rightarrow A$  as $g(x)=f(x,z)-f'(x,z)$ then i have 
$$f'(x,y)=f(x,y)-xg(y)+g(xy)-f(x,yz)+f'(x,yz)$$

I have got something similar to what i need but this is not complete..

Please suggest some hints

Comment: i cannot tell what «the second part is»...

Comment: you wrote a looong text and then that you do not know how to do the second part, but it is not clear at all what the second part is! You should try to make your question easy to understand, so that people can understand it easily.

Comment: i have edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 2nd quest is still open.

By $s(x)s'(x)^{-1} \in \ker(p)=\text{im}(i)$ and injectivity of $i$ there is a unique $g(x) \in A$ such that $i(g(x))=s(x)s'(x)^{-1}$. This defines a function $g:G \to A$.

Before we can deduce the formula in part (ii) of the question, it's important to note that the action of $G$ on $A$ is defined by $i(g\cdot a) := s(x)i(a) s(x)^{-1}=s'(x)i(a)s'(x)^{-1}$.

Now we are ready for the computation:

$$i(f(x,y))=s(x)s(y)s(xy)^{-1}=i(g(x))s'(x)s(y)s(xy)^{-1}$$
$$=i(g(x))s'(x)i(g(y))s'(y)s(xy)^{-1}=i(g(x))i(x\cdot g(y))s'(x)s'(y)s(xy)^{-1}$$
$$=i(g(x)+x\cdot g(y))i(f'(x,y))s'(xy)s(xy)^{-1}=i(g(x)+x\cdot g(y)+f'(x,y))i(g(xy))^{-1}$$
$$=i(g(x)+x\cdot g(y)+f'(x,y)-g(xy))$$

Canceling $i$ on both sides yields the sought-after formula.

N.b. In modern language $f$ is called a *2-cocycle* and the function $f'-f$ is called a *2-coboundary*.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer... I was expecting only a better hint ... The problem was i did not know where to start.. I have seen your first equality $i(f(x,y))=s(x)s(y)s(xy)^{-1}$ and then i tried on my own... I got it... thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sections $s$, $s':G\to E$, then for all $g\in G$ we have that $s(g)$ and $s'(g)$ are two elements of $E$ with the same image in $G$: it follows that there exists a unique $t(g)\in A$ such that $s(g)=t(g)s'(g)$.

Figure out what consequences this has in terms of the factor sets corresponding to $s$ and $s'$.

Comment: i am sorry... i did not  get what you have said....

Comment: **What** did you not understand?

Comment: what is $t(g)$ :O

Comment: Since $p(s(g))=p(s'(g))$, so that $p(s(g)s'(g)^{-1})=1_G$, the element $s(g)s'(g)^{-1}$ is in the kernel of the map $p$, which is $A$, so there is an element $t(g)\in A$ such that $t(g)=s(g)s'(g)^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok.. Let me tell you what i understood.... For fixed $p$ i have $s,s'$ such that $ps=ps'=1_G$ In particular i have $p(s(g))=p(s'(g))$ thus i have $s(g)(s'(g))^{-1}\in ker (p)=i(A)$ thus i have an element $e(g)\in i(A)$ such that $e(g)=s(g)(s'(g))^{-1}$ but why is "we have that s(g) and s′(g) are two elements of E with the same image in G" relevant here :O

Comment: The phrase «$s(g)$ and $s′(g)$ are two elements of $E$ with the same image in $G$» means exactly the same as «$p(s(g))=p(s'(g))$.» ...

Comment: Ok.. so, you are suggesting me to cosnider $e : G\rightarrow A$ with $g\mapsto e(g)$ that i have above.... Is that so.. I have also tried some thing in question body... please have a look at that..

Comment: What you did in what you wrote is to consider the difference $f(x,z)-f'(x,z)$ (for some fixed $z$ which you did not specify) and as far as I can tell that has nothing to do with my function $t$.

Comment: I do not see how i can use this... I have $s(x)\cdot s(x')=i(f(x,x'))s(xx')$ and $s'(x)s'(x')=i(f'(x,x'))s'(xx')$... I am totally lost.... i request you to give one more hint...

Comment: Well, I think you should play with this more by yourself. You have all the time in the world!

Comment: Actually i don't have :) (No offense).... I tried something as a choice of map which was natural but then i could not solve in that way... the map you suggested is not natural in first look.. :O I will try my best...

Comment: The map I suggested is natural: is measures precisely the difference between the two sections.

Comment: my map $f(x,z)-f'(x,z)$ is also measures the difference between two factor sets :O

Comment: But you do not really want to measure the difference beetween the factors sets: you want to measure how the change of section affects the factor set, so the natural thing is to start with a measure of the difference between the sections... In any case, I suggest you keep trying with your approach as much as you want.

Comment: I tried my best with the thought that i have in my mind... every thing is fine except that i have $$f'(x,y)=f(x,y)+g(xy)-xg(y)-f(x,yz)+f'(x,yz)$$  instead of $$f'(x,y)=f(x,y)+g(xy)-xg(y)-g(x)$$

This says $g(x)=f(x,yz)-f'(x,yz)$ but i have considered $g(x)=f(x,z)-f'(x,z)$ I do not understand why $f(x,yz)-f'(x,yz)=f(x,z)-f'(x,z)$ has to be true..

Comment: Well, it does not have to be true.

Comment: yes... it does not have to be.... I tried with what you have suggested but that is going nowhere... :(

Comment: Can you please help me to settle this problem.... :(